# Configuration of wordpress with existing html websites javascripts and other files

Tags: wordpress, postgresql

We want to move out our normal html website to wordpress. We have our blogs on wordpress but now want to bring up whole site on it. But before this move we want to test it on stage wordpress.
So want to know what all steps we need to follow for configuring the stage wordpress with postgresql database. 
We have the email subscription form on every html page where we validate the emails by checking whether the user is already registered or not in the postgresql db. What are the correct steps? Or by using javascript can it be done?
How this can be implemented on stage server wordpress? 
Please help. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/ -->> Wordpress is mysql-only (and it is very hard to modify, because the DB-accessing code is scattered all over the place; last time I checked) ,  so you are doomed.

Comment: Its done. Included websites js in the root of wordpress and calling them from page. Also mentioned all js in functions.php